# activate custom sidebar widgets

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

Hey guys I'm trying to activate a sidebar for wp widgets.

So my HTML looks like this:

```
<aside id="leftSidebar">
   <section>
      <h3></h3>
      <div class="contents"></div>
   </section>
</aside>
```

So I want to put the widget inside "contents" and its title in h3 tag. How my activate function should be and what php to put in my html if needed? I didn't find any examples near mine so I appreciate any help 10x a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You would register the sidebar in the functions.php file with something like this:**

```
<?php
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'custom-content',
 'before_widget' => '<section>',
 'after_widget' => "</section>",
 'before_title' => '<h3>',
 'after_title' => "</h3>"
  ));
?>
```

**And Use it in your theme like this:**

```
<div class="contents">
<?php if ( function_exists(dynamic_sidebar(1) ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar(custom-content); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you were very helpful.
It worked fine with little modifications.